# Error searching remote flathub: Can't find ref org.fedoraproject.MediaWriter

Tags: fedora, linux-mint, liveusb, flatpak

I'm trying to install Fedora Media Writer in Linux Mint 19.3.

I get:

> Error searching remote flathub: Can't find ref org.fedoraproject.MediaWriter"

so I've tried:

```
$ flatpak remote-add --user --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
$ flatpak update
$ flatpak remote-modify --enable flathub
$ flatpak install flathub org.fedoraproject.MediaWriter
```

But the result is the same error.